# Where to find the error messages of Postfix

Tags: ubuntu, logs, postfix

I cannot sent mail by using Postfix (SMTP) on Ubuntu Server 11.04.
So, there must be some errors,
But where to see the error message?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Have you already stumbled upon this comprehensive **Postfix Debugging Howto**?](http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html)  There's the following notice concerning logging:

> Postfix logs all failed and successful deliveries to a logfile. The file is usually called `/var/log/maillog` or `/var/log/mail`; the exact pathname is defined in the `/etc/syslog.conf` file.

(`syslog.conf` specifies where the `mail`-facility logs get written to, it's rather self-explaining when you look at it.)

Comment: I don't have this file, I'm using ubuntu server 11.0

Comment: No `/etc/syslog.conf`?  Sorry, I don't know much about Ubuntu.  Forget this then, how about `/var/log/mail` or similar?  According to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/postfix.html#postfix-logs), there should be a `/var/log/mail.err` log, I suppose.  You'll find some Ubuntu-specific Postfix debugging hints on that page, too.

Comment: /var/log/mail.err   this is it! Are all unix log file puted in this /var/log dir? Is it a 'must be'?

Comment: [For system logs this is mostly true](http://linux.die.net/man/7/hier), possibly varying for different distributions (and of course user-space programs, e.g. `~/.xsession-errors` on some distributions).

Comment: On ubuntu, the syslogger is rsyslog. The configuration file is /etc/rsyslog.conf and in the /etc/rsyslog.d/ directory. In your case, /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf say 'mail.* -/var/log/mail.log' and 'mail.err /var/log/mail.err'

Answer (score 6):

log files for postfix 
can be

```
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.info
```

and also you can grep logs for `/var/log/syslog` file.

Comment: I found mine in `/usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog`, of all places. (CentOS server managed by Plesk.)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to locate logs anywhere and I was running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, turns out this was a permission issue for some strange reason. the problem was with the syslog permission. The following helped me to resolve it:

```
sudo chown syslog:adm /var/log
sudo chmod 0775 /var/log

sudo service rsyslog restart
sudo service postfix restart
```